# Exception while loading an image from gallery in flutter

Tags: flutter, exception, imagepicker

I tried to load an image from gallery the code throw an Exception .
The Exception is :Unhandled Exception: type 'PickedFile' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast
This is my code:

```
_imgFromGallery() async {
PickedFile image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
if (image == null)
  return null;
setState(() {
  _isloading = false;
  _image = image as File;
});
classify(image as File);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because you're trying to cast a `PickedFile` into a `File`. You can give the `path` property of your `PickedFile` to a `File` constructor instead.

```dart
...
setState(() {
  _isloading = false;
  _image = File(image.path)
});
classify(File(image.path));
...
```